# Unit test coverage report does not include the mocked methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm writing unit tests in Python for a company project. We use Django as a framework and coverage.py to track the progress. Recently I start adding -m to see which lines I'm missing to cover. So the command I use is:

> "coverage run --source='app1,app2' manage.py test && coverage report -m"

Example of one of the methods:

```
def _read_from_disk(self, excel_kwargs):
    """
    Read excel file from disk and apply excel_kwargs.

    Args:
        excel_kwargs: Parameters for pandas.read_excel.

    Returns:
        DataFrame or dict of DataFrames.
    """
    return pd.read_excel(self.location, **excel_kwargs)
```

And my unit test for this method

```
@patch("data.excel.BaseExcelReader._read_from_disk")
def test__read_from_disk_compare_data_frames(self, df_mock_svd):
    df_mock_svd.return_value = pd.read_excel(data_frame_to_excel_test(self.excel_data, "SvD Data"))

    df = self.test_reader._read_from_disk(self.excel_kwargs_svd)
    df_mock_svd.assert_called_once_with(self.excel_kwargs_svd)
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, pd.DataFrame({"test_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}))
```

The problem is that when I run the command the coverage report does not count the method as covered. I this is my first question here, so if I did not specify the question right, I'm sorry.

Comment: That is because it is not covered. You basically replace it with another implementation and test the replacement. If you would patch `read_excel` instead, it would be covered.

Comment: Maybe I need to change the question to how to @patch for pd.excel_read.

Comment: @patch("raven.data.excel.BaseExcelReader._read_from_disk.read_excel") or @patch("raven.data.excel.BaseExcelReader._read_from_disk.pd.read_excel") If i tried it this way I receive error: AttributeError: <function BaseExcelReader._read_from_disk at 0x0000029163BD6048> does not have the attribute 'read_excel'

Comment: Please write a new question, if you have another problem (e.g. how to mock xyz) - the current question has already been answered in the comments (by @NedBatchelder and myself, e.g. the coverage report is correct). Separate questions in the comments won't be found and are also not quite readable.